# How can I Add Custom Text Message to Login Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, custom, admin-login

How can I add a Custom Text Message to Login Page in my Magento 2 store? can anyone help me with a step-by-step method for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Adding Custom Text to Login Page

You can add any kind of block to the login page from the admin panel. Here is a sample for the same:

First things first, Log in into the Magento 2 admin panel.

Now,

Follow the below mentioned steps:

### Step 1.

In the left pane, under **CONTENT,** click **Blocks**.

### Step 2.

In the upper-right corner, click the **Add New Block** button.

### Step 3.

Fill in the fields as required, and then click **Save** in the upper-right corner.

### Step 4.

To create a new widget, under **CONTENT** in the left pane, click **Widgets.**

### Step 5.

In the upper-right corner, click the **Add Widget** button.

### Step 6.

In the **Type** box, select **CMS Static Block.**

### Step 7.

In the **Design Theme** box, select the currently active theme on your store, and then click **Continue**.

### Step 8.

Under **Storefront Properties,** in the **Widget Title** field, name the widget.

You should also specify one or more store views to make your widget active. Specify sort order.

### Step 9.

Under **Layout Updates**, set layout properties as required.

For instance,  in the **Display on** box, we’ve selected **Specified Page** and set this block to the **After Page Header** place.

To cover add custom text to the login page, select:

Display On―Specified Page

Page―Customer Account Login Form

Container―as required

### Step 10.

Under the **Widget Options** tab, select the recently created block.

### Step 11.

In the upper-right corner, click **Save**, and then clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Locate the magento template where you want to make your modification...login page isn't enough, the login page is built of multiplate templates like all other magento templates.

I'm not a front dev so, my glitch would be simple as that...open the development tool of your browser...check the html code around the place where you want to add your text.

Step 2 : Once you got the template, you simply needs to override it (Paste the original file plus your modification)  in your custom theme in `app/design/YOUR_THEME_PATH/MAGENTO_MODULE_NAME/templates/PATH_TO_TEMPLATE`

caps are to replace with your own data depending on your theme and the file you want to override.